# convert json Array to single Json Object

Tags: php, json

I was wonder whether it is possible to convert a json Array to a single json object in php?

I mean below json Array:

```
[{'x':'y','k':'l'}, {'q':'w', 'r':'t'}]
```

Can be converted to:

```
{'0':{'x':'y','k':'l'}, '1':{'q':'w', 'r':'t'}}
```

Comment: Then it will become a 1D array

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with the [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) parameter

```
$json = "[{'x':'y','k':'l'}, {'q':'w', 'r':'t'}]";
$array = json_decode($json, true);  // convert our JSON to a PHP array
$result = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // convert back to JSON as an object

echo $result; // {"0":{"x":"y","k":"l"},"1":{"q":"w","r":"t"}}
```

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**
>
> Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
$array[] = array('x' => 'y','k' => '1');
$array[] = array('q' => 'w','r' => 't');
echo json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```